# Google Apps Script with three similar functions

Tags: google-apps-script, scope

I'm somewhat intermediate at programming in general, and this is my first Google Apps Script.

I had recognized that I needed to asynchronously call `getCapitalOneEmails()`, `getChaseEmails()`, and `getBofAEmails()`, so I refactored the code to what I've included below. I then trigger `getEmails()` with a time-based trigger. And, because GAS doesn't support ES6, I compiled the code to ES3 using Google's [closure compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). The compiled script isn't giving me any errors in the GAS editor, but it's still not actually working.

The script I've put together below is commented throughout, so I won't explain what it does here.

**EDIT**: After realizing *I don't really need the functions to fire async*(they're looking for different email labels, so they don't need to happen after each other), I simplified the `getEmails()` function, below. Now there are no errors due to ES6, but the data seems to be missing. The final `addDataToSpreadsheet()` fires but no data is input. Would this be because I'm using the same variable names for the data passed to `addDataToSpreadsheet()`?

```
/*
 * This Google Apps Script is running inside my selected
 * spreadsheet, so any reference to getActiveSpreadsheet() method
 * will create a new sheet within that context.
 * 
 */

// This function creates a new monthly sheet
function createMonthlySheet() {
    // Get a new formatted date object
    var currentMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'MM/yyyy');
    // Insert formatted date string from above
    var sheetName = currentMonthYear;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // Create the new sheet
    ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 0);
    // Now get the newly-create currently active sheet
    var newSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    // Get all sheets
    var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    // Get the next oldest sheet
    var oldSheet = allSheets[1];
    // Hide the old one
    oldSheet.hideSheet();

    // Set our monthly budget amount
    var budgetAmt = 1510;
    // Set H1 to the active cell
    var budgetCell = newSheet.setActiveSelection('H1');
    // Set H1 to our monthly budget
    budgetCell.setValue(budgetAmt);
    // Set the number format to US-style currency
    budgetCell.setNumberFormat('$#,##0.00');

    // Set F1 as the active cell
    var sumCell = newSheet.setActiveSelection('F1');
    // Set the formula to the sum of column D
    sumCell.setFormula('=SUM(D:D)');

    // Set L1 as the active cell
    var diffCell = newSheet.setActiveSelection('L1');
    // Set the formula to the sum of budgetCell - sumCell
    diffCell.setFormula('=SUM(H1,-(F1))');
    // Set the number format to US-style currency
    diffCell.setNumberFormat('$#,##0.00');

    // Get column D
    var range = newSheet.getRange('D:D');
    // Set column D as the active range
    var moneyCol = newSheet.setActiveRange(range);
    // Set the number format to US-style currency
    moneyCol.setNumberFormat('$#,##0.00');
}

// This function fires different functions for each email label
function getEmails() {
    getCapitalOneEmails();
    getChaseEmails();
    getBofAEmails();
}

// This function fetches CapitalOne transaction emails and parses the data
function getCapitalOneEmails() {
    // Set a variable to our "CapitalOne Transaction" label in Gmail
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('CapitalOne Transaction');
    if (label) {
        var threads = label.getThreads(); // Get threads of label above
        for (var i in threads) {
            var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); // Get messages in threads
            for (var j in messages) {
                if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
                    // Only get unread messages
                    var emailBody = messages[j].getPlainBody(); // Get email body in plaintext, no HTML
                    Logger.log('Email body: ' + emailBody);

                    // This sets out data variables to an empty string initially
                    var message_account = '',
                        message_date = '',
                        message_vendor = '',
                        message_amount = '';

                    // Get account number
                    var regExpAcct = /RE\: Account ending in (\d{4})/; // regex to find 4-digit account number
                    var CO_message_account = regExpAcct.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CO_message_account) {
                        message_account = CO_message_account[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message accnt: ' + message_account);
                    }

                    // Get date of transaction
                    var regExpDate = /we're notifying you that on (...+), at/; // regex to find date
                    var CO_message_date = regExpDate.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CO_message_date) {
                        message_date = CO_message_date[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message date: ' + message_date);
                    }

                    // Get vendor name
                    var regExpVendor = /, at (...+),/; // regex to find transaction vendor name
                    var CO_message_vendor = regExpVendor.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CO_message_vendor) {
                        message_vendor = CO_message_vendor[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message vendor: ' + message_vendor);
                    }

                    // Get transaction amount
                    var regExpAmount = /purchase in the amount of \$(\S+) was/; // regex to find transaction amount
                    var CO_message_amount = regExpAmount.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CO_message_amount) {
                        message_amount = CO_message_amount[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message amount: ' + message_amount);
                    }

                    // Calls the function, below, that adds the data to the spreadsheet, with our data inserted as parameters
                    addDataToSpreadsheet(
                        message_date,
                        message_account,
                        message_vendor,
                        message_amount
                    );
                    messages[j].markRead(); // Mark the message as read to end
                }
            }
        }
    } // End if(label)
}

// This function fetches Chase(Amazon) transaction emails and parses the data
function getChaseEmails() {
    // Set a variable to our "Chase Transaction" label in Gmail
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Chase Transaction');
    if (label) {
        var threads = label.getThreads(); // Get threads of label above
        for (var i in threads) {
            var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); // Get messages in threads
            for (var j in messages) {
                if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
                    // Only get unread messages
                    var emailBody = messages[j].getPlainBody(); // Get email body in plaintext, no HTML
                    Logger.log('Email body: ' + emailBody);

                    // This sets out data variables to an empty string initially
                    var message_account = '',
                        message_date = '',
                        message_vendor = '',
                        message_amount = '';

                    // Get account number
                    var regExpAcct = /help you manage your credit card account ending in (\d{4})/; // regex to find 4-digit account number
                    var CH_message_account = regExpAcct.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CH_message_account) {
                        message_account = CH_message_account[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message accnt: ' + message_account);
                    }

                    // Get date of transaction
                    var regExpDate = /we're notifying you that on (...+), at/; // regex to find date
                    var CH_message_date = regExpDate.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CH_message_date) {
                        message_date = CH_message_date[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message date: ' + message_date);
                    }

                    // Get vendor name
                    var regExpVendor = /has been authorized on (...+) EST./; // regex to find transaction vendor name
                    var CH_message_vendor = regExpVendor.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CH_message_vendor) {
                        message_vendor = CH_message_vendor[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message vendor: ' + message_vendor);
                    }

                    // Get transaction amount
                    var regExpAmount = /This charge of \($USD\) (\S+) at /; // regex to find transaction amount
                    var CH_message_amount = regExpAmount.exec(emailBody);
                    if (CH_message_amount) {
                        message_amount = CH_message_amount[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message amount: ' + message_amount);
                    }

                    // Calls the function, below, that adds the data to the spreadsheet, with our data inserted as parameters
                    addDataToSpreadsheet(
                        message_date,
                        message_account,
                        message_vendor,
                        message_amount
                    );
                    messages[j].markRead(); // Mark the message as read to end
                }
            }
        }
    } // End if(label)
}

// This function fetches Bank of America transaction emails and parses the data
function getBofAEmails() {
    // Set a variable to our "BofA Transaction" label in Gmail
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('BofA Transaction');
    if (label) {
        var threads = label.getThreads(); // Get threads of label above
        for (var i in threads) {
            var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); // Get messages in threads
            for (var j in messages) {
                if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
                    // Only get unread messages
                    var emailBody = messages[j].getPlainBody(); // Get email body in plaintext, no HTML
                    Logger.log('Email body: ' + emailBody);

                    // This sets out data variables to an empty string initially
                    var message_account = '',
                        message_date = '',
                        message_vendor = '',
                        message_amount = '';

                    // Get account number
                    var regExpAcct = /RE\: Account ending in (\d{4})/; // regex to find 4-digit account number
                    var BA_message_account = regExpAcct.exec(emailBody);
                    if (BA_message_account) {
                        message_account = BA_message_account[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message accnt: ' + message_account);
                    }

                    // Get date of transaction
                    var regExpDate = /we're notifying you that on (...+), at/; // regex to find date
                    var BA_message_date = regExpDate.exec(emailBody);
                    if (BA_message_date) {
                        message_date = BA_message_date[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message date: ' + message_date);
                    }

                    // Get vendor name
                    var regExpVendor = /, at (...+),/; // regex to find transaction vendor name
                    var BA_message_vendor = regExpVendor.exec(emailBody);
                    if (BA_message_vendor) {
                        message_vendor = BA_message_vendor[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message vendor: ' + message_vendor);
                    }

                    // Get transaction amount
                    var regExpAmount = /purchase in the amount of \$(\S+) was/; // regex to find transaction amount
                    var BA_message_amount = regExpAmount.exec(emailBody);
                    if (BA_message_amount) {
                        message_amount = BA_message_amount[1]; // Insert Group 1 got data from regex execution to variable
                        Logger.log('Email message amount: ' + message_amount);
                    }

                    // Calls the function, below, that adds the data to the spreadsheet, with our data inserted as parameters
                    addDataToSpreadsheet(
                        message_date,
                        message_account,
                        message_vendor,
                        message_amount
                    );
                    messages[j].markRead(); // Mark the message as read to end
                }
            }
        }
    } // End if(label)
}

function addDataToSpreadsheet(date, account, vendor, amount) {
    var rowData = [date, account, vendor, amount];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000);
    try {
        sheet
            .insertRowBefore(2)
            .getRange(2, 1, 1, rowData.length)
            .setValues([rowData]);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } finally {
        lock.releaseLock();
    }
    var range = sheet.getRange('D:D');
    var moneyCol = sheet.setActiveRange(range);
    moneyCol.setNumberFormat('$#,##0.00');
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `async function ()` declaration and it's causing problems in the script editor.  Have you debugged this code in the script editor.

Comment: `async` is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

If I put the pre-compiled code in the GAS editor, I get an error: "Missing ; before statement. (line 56, file "Code")" <--this is located at the `async function getEmails() {` line.

Comment: Yes.  Google Apps Scripts is generally built around Javascript 1.6.  But there other more knowledgeable volunteers around so I'll let them answer your questions.

Comment: As @Cooper said, `async` is not supported, AFAIK.

Comment: That wasn't really my issue because I was compiling the code to a supported type, as I mentioned in my OP. I've edited my question to clarify the issue, which I think has more to do with scope than anything else now.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What meaning is ``the data seems to be missing``? 2. About the functions of ``getCapitalOneEmails()``, ``getChaseEmails()`` and ``getBofAEmails()``, when you checked the values which are given to ``addDataToSpreadsheet()``, could you confirm the correct values you want? If those values have no values, the empty row is inserted. 3. Can I ask you about the reason that you use ``LockService``? 4. What is the function ``createMonthlySheet()``? It seems that this function is not used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Once I figured out that I didn't need the `getCapitalOneEmails()`, `getChaseEmails()` and `getBofAEmails()` to fire asynchronously, I found that my regexes seemed to be slightly off—thus the empty variables/data. I fixed those and the data was inserted fine.